# Typescript Module augmentation angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I m trying to use module augmentation in angular 12, and when i add ts file with

```
declare module '@angular/forms' {
 export interface AbstractControl {
   metadata: Map<string, any>[];
 }
}
```

all work fine, i can  use my metadata properties in FormControl.

But visual studio code show me an error :

[image]

If i remove my declaration, i dont have error anymore but i don't have my metadata accessible.

**Info**

angular ~12.2.5

typescript ^4.3.5

What i missed?

**#EDIT1**

Finally, after checking my repository, i see that i have 2 files for moduleaugmentation.ts :(. I forgot to delete an old one of a previous test.

But If i want to don't have error anymore i need to have an import line at the top of my moduleaugmentation.ts. I don't know why.

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

declare module '@angular/forms' {
  export interface AbstractControl {
    metadata: Map<string, any>[];
  }
}
```

The import is mark as unused but if i remove it, error come again.

**#EDIT1 End**

Thanks!

Comment: Did you import the module beforehand in that file?

Comment: You mean Import AbstractControl before declare module? Yes i have try this. And if i launch the app all work fine, its juste an error in vs code

Comment: @GunnarB. i edit my post, i have find why! but i have another strange behavour with import...but all work fine. Thanks for the time